# Enable DVD Resume on XBMC?

Tags: windows-7, dvd, kodi

Is it possible to enable some kind of automatic "DVD Resume" in XBMC when playing DVD discs?

At the moment the only way I see of doing something like this is by setting a bookmark, which is a bit of a pain to do when compared to my old DVD player which could resume from multiple discs even when they had been removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DVD resume is now implemented in XBMC, I tested it on XBMC Frodo alpha 4 and it works fine.

[commit on GitHub](https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc/pull/349)